# How to open VRML(*.wrl ) file in iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, vrml

I have VRML(*.wrl ) file & I want to open that file inside my iOS application. Is there any way to do this i.e. any SDK, or other way. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[**Cortona3D**](http://www.cortona3d.com/Products/Viewer/Cortona3D-Viewer-for-iOS.aspx) is a very good viewer for .wrl files:

[image: Cortona3D for iOS]

---

But if you want to make your own app and don't mind the steep price and sub-par documentation, you could use [**BS Contact iOS**](http://www.bitmanagement.com/en/download) instead (although no app that uses this viewer ever reached the App Store).

Comment: anyone know what's Cortona3D's url schema that I could call to lauch specific .WRL file?

Comment: Better ask them directly at support@cortona3d.com

Comment: Although if you browse a page in Safari Mobile and click an URL that ends in `.wrl`, it will ask you if you want to open it in Cortona3D, without needing a special url schema.